# How to send a LINE FEED character via CIMD

Tags: nokia

I have designed an application, which sends message from an application to a mobile number. It uses the CIMD protocol, developed by Nokia. The application is working fine except for the NEW LINE FEED. It does not send the LINE FEED character. According to Nokia's document   "CIMD_Interface_Specification_SC70",  `_XXascii(10)` should be used for LINE FEED, but it's not.